# Achieving the best possible performance in OpenCL on different machines

Tags: opencl

As OpenCL programs run on several machines each with its particular architecture, this question comes to mind that how should I write my program to get the best average performance on those machines.

I'd be happy to hear your advises :)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

My vendor-agnostic OpenCL optimization advice, in order:

Memory Access

1. While memory bandwidth in GPUs is phenomenal, it is often the largest bottleneck in many kernels. Therefore, minimize memory reads and writes. Don't read anything twice that could be stored in a variable.
2. Related to (1), make it so adjacent kernels access adjacent memory locations so the GPU can coalesce the accesses into single (often 128-bit or wider) reads or writes. In general, prefer wide accesses over narrow ones (for example, if you have a data structure with four single byte elements, read it as a single uchar4 instead of doing four uchar reads).
3. If you have global data where the same values get used inside multiple work items, utilize shared local memory so you're only reading from global memory once. Shared local memory is much faster to access.
4. Interleave memory and compute if you can, instead of doing all of one and then all of the other. The GPU overlaps these so one of them becomes "free".

Compute

1. Use float instead of double. They are much faster.
2. If you can tolerate lower precision, use the native_ functions as they are often faster.
3. Provide enough work items to keep the GPU busy. Global work size should be at least thousands of items, but tens of thousands or more is better. Anything below 1000 is going to leave cores idle.
4. Avoid branching. If work items within a work group have divergent branching the GPU will have to take both paths and use predicates to mask writes on the non-active sides. Branching that is consistent within a work group isn't a problem.
5. Avoid giant kernels. Most compilers inline all function calls. GPU have a limited amount of shared register store, so kernels that use a large number of registers can limit the number of in-flight work groups.

Host side

1. You mentioned programs, but another important aspect is getting data onto and off of the GPU. Many GPUs can do this at the same time as compute, but you need to use separate command queues and events to ensure everything is ready when you need it. It is challenging, but can turn serial upload/compute/download cycles into parallel ones (upload of C, compute of B, and download of A all happening at the same time).
2. If data transfer is a big part of where your time gets spent, investigate pinned memory, zero-copy transfer, and vendor-specific memory buffer creation flags that can help here.
3. Avoid clFinish and blocking read/writes if possible, in order to keep the command queue from being empty and then the GPU idle.

Good luck, have fun, and benchmark on your target hardware to make sure your optimizations are positive on all hardware and not regress on some.

Comment: Regarding point 4 under memory access, you will run into a problem if the compute operation depends on the memory operation.  If they are independent then great, go for it.  Otherwise, grouping all memory reads, followed by all compute operations, can allow the GPU to extract a bit of instruction level parallelism as memory reads are asynchronous - they only block when a computer operation needs their result.

Comment: Thank you so much, but should I consider anything else as I'm targeting CPU architectures as well ?

Comment: Be prepared for the CPU implementations to be OK but perhaps not as fast as hand-tuned native code. Also, _image_ read/write is emulated on CPU and not particularly fast.